# How do you access a custom view's android:layout_width and android:layout_height parameters?

Tags: android, view

How do you access your custom view's android:layout_width and android:layout_height values?

Sample xml:

```
<com.example.CustomButton
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp" />
```

In CustomButton:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    int measuredWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    int measuredHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
    // How can we measure based on android:layout_width, android:layout_height?
    // Currently this implementation measures off the parent's values
    setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must get the layout params of the view:

```
CustomButton.LayoutParams viewParams = yourView.getLayoutParams();
```

And then you can access or modify the width or view:

```
viewParams.height;
viewParams.width;
```

Hope it helps!